# What benefit do Captchas provide?

Tags: web-service, captcha

I have researched and found the following sites which will break captchas:

- anticaptcha
- 2captcha

(links not included to prevent promoting the sites)

Given that these services can be used to break captchas, what is the benefit in using captchas, especially as they can impact human users?

Comment: What are you basing captchas being useless on?

Comment: *"...recaptcha is useless against automated form submissions..."* - is it? Please provide prove or a reference for your claim - but make sure that it actually applies to the current version of reCaptcha and not to some older one.

Comment: haven't you heard of captcha solving services, 2captcha, anticaptcha?? anyone who wants to submit forms automatically uses them, so recaptcha is useless now

Answer (score 5):

"given that there are locksmiths, what's the point of locking your door?"

Just because something has limitations doesn't mean it's useless. Those services cost money, maybe more money than an auto-registered account is worth. There are also classes of attackers who don't have access to those kind of services. InfoSec is often a numbers game, and capthas are a cheap (not perfect) way to give bigger numbers to the good guys.

Answer (score 5):

Your linked sources seem to be pay-to-solve captcha services. These certainly make captchas *less* effective, but they certainly don't make them useless.

Lets look at the numbers, since this is a numbers game.

Recently, my company had a brute force issue where one of our web facing portals was brute forced - they'd try each user they knew about in turn, trying 3 passwords, then going to the next user. They were averaging about 2000 attempts per second. We solved this issue by placing a captcha portal in front of the login page.

Your linked sources each quote a ~7 second solving time for each captcha, and quote $0.50 per 1000 image.

So, to perform the same attack against my server, they'd take two significant effectiveness hits -

First, they'd be solving 2000 attempts in 7 seconds, rather than in 1 second. This is, obviously, only 1/7th as fast a rate. It will take them 7x longer to find one working password. This isn't astronomically high, and if it was free, it might be worth the effort anyways.

Second, they'd be paying 1 dollar per seven seconds of attack time (.5 per 1000 captchas, 2000 solved per seven seconds - $1 per seven seconds). If they are doing this attack for one day, they're out ~12000 dollars. (60 * 60 * 24 / 7)

The main goal to brute force accounts like this is to steal information to be sold or used in later attacks. The return on the accounts they DO get in one day will almost never equal $12000. The attack becomes uneconomically viable unless you're attacking something very very important.

Comment: you are only paying for solved captchas ...so your captchas are pretty much useless

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me, could you please clarify what you mean? Either the captchas are solved and these figures are accurate or they're unsolved and no brute force attempt can occur.

Answer (score 2):

## How captchas work

The idea of a captcha is to find a task that is difficult for a machine to do, but easy for a human to do. This is mean to defend an action that only a human should be performing.

The idea is not necessarily to stop all bots, but to slow down the bots, by making attacking the site more expensive in at least one of the following ways:

- Compute power
- Price
- Time

If the bots have a higher than human failure rate, this can be used to detect them, and further defences can be used at that point.

## Captcha types

- Asking 1 of a pool of questions

  - This is easy for a human, but can be easy for a system using natural language processing too
- Reading basic text

  - This is relatively easy, Optical Charater Recognition is relatively simple compared to other challenges
- Reading modified text

  - This makes reading harder for machines, but also for humans, and some research has machines getting higher solve rates than humans.
- Reading photos

  - This can be difficult, but there are algorithms that can do it
- Identifying objects in photos

  - This is a lot harder, see [Google's birds and bikes challenge](https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/09/introducing-unrestricted-adversarial.html) for an example of a task for a human that is a lot harder for a machine.
- Human actions

  - By "watching" how the user moves their mouse, types on their keyboard, or various other factors, they can be given a score of how likely they are to be a bot

## Captcha breaking services

Captcha breaking services work by one of a few methods:

- Trying to write an algorithm to complete the challenges

  For some older captchas this may be possible, but for many newer ones this would require breakthroughs in areas of research to do so with any reasonable accuracy.
- Trying to break the defences of the captcha

  This works against some badly implemented captchas, but is relatively rare compared to other attacks.
- Using humans to break the captcha

  This adds a cost, which means that although they can still be broken, the cost per action is orders of magnitude higher than without a captcha in place.